Superscript asterisks in several expressions in a row using annotate in ggplot2
I need to put three expressions as an annotation to a ggplot2 graph. All three expressions together refer to the same point in my graph. Thus, I want to unite them in one expression in a row and place with the function annotate() at one graph coordinate.
Each of these three sub-expressions contains asterisks that should be in superscript (significant coefficients of three model outputs). Currently, I am using the paste() command together with parse = TRUE. And it is working, if all expressions are separated by a slash like that: "/".
However, I don´t want slashes between the three sub-expressions. I want to have spaces there. And I want to be able to change the number of those spaces. However, when I remove the slashes from my code, it does not work any more.
Thus: How could I unite all three sub-expression in one expression at the same coordinate and also make the asterisks in all of them being in superscript?
# The following code (with slashes) is working fine:

Dummy_df \<- as.data.frame(cbind("Var1" = c(0, 177),
"Var2" = c(0, 177)))

ggplot(Dummy_df, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2)) +
geom_point(size = 0.1, colour = "white") +
theme_light() +
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
panel.border = element_blank(),
panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_blank()) +
xlab(" ") +
ylab(" ") +
annotate("text", label = paste('2.16^"***"', "/", '5.48^"***"', "/", '1.92^"***"'),
x = 40.75, y = 138, parse = TRUE, size = 5)

But this code...
ggplot(Dummy_df, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2)) +
geom_point(size = 0.1, colour = "white") +
theme_light() +
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
panel.border = element_blank(),
panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_blank()) +
xlab(" ") +
ylab(" ") +
annotate("text", label = paste('2.16^"***"', " ", '5.48^"***"', " ", '1.92^"***"'),
x = 40.75, y = 138, parse = TRUE, size = 5)

...and this code
ggplot(Dummy_df, aes(x = Var1, y = Var2)) +
geom_point(size = 0.1, colour = "white") +
theme_light() +
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
panel.border = element_blank(),
panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_blank()) +
xlab(" ") +
ylab(" ") +
annotate("text", label = paste('2.16^"***"', '5.48^"***"', '1.92^"***"'),
x = 40.75, y = 138, parse = TRUE, size = 5)

both throw up the following error:
Error in `annotate()`:
! Problem while converting geom to grob.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `parse()`:
! \<text\>:1:14: unexpected numeric constant
1: 2.16^"***"   5.48
^
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.


The issue is that your for your non-working codes the labels are no valid ?plotmath expressions, i.e. if you want a space between the single items you have to separate or concatenate them using a ~ and if no space is required separate or concatenate with a *. In the first example it works as you are using / which makes your label a valid math expression.
library(ggplot2)

base <- ggplot()

base +
  annotate("text",
    label = paste('2.16^"*"', '5.48^"*"', '1.92^"*"', sep = "/"),
    x = 40.75, y = 150, parse = TRUE, size = 5
  ) +
  annotate("text",
    label = paste('2.16^"***"', '5.48^"***"', '1.92^"***"', sep = "~"),
    x = 40.75, y = 100, parse = TRUE, size = 5
  )  +
  annotate("text",
    label = paste('2.16^"***"', '5.48^"***"', '1.92^"***"', sep = "*"),
    x = 40.75, y = 50, parse = TRUE, size = 5
  )



Thank you cordially, Stefan. It is a really prompt and clear answer that saved my whole work of today.
